# frenchb in babel produces compilation error with \NewDocumentCommand

Tags: babel

Not sure if this is a `LaTeX3` issue or not, but in the code below the presence of `frenchb` in the `babel` parameters causes a compilation error. The MWE below has been boiled down from a large chunk of code to narrow down the error and it is for this reason that, on its own, it may look somewhat contrived.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
%-----------------------------
%RN. Sunday 23 August 2015
%   ISSUE:
% Let it be debatable whether my two \NewDocumentCommands are all
% that clever, or even make sense, the fact is they work. If frenchb
% is included as a parameter in babel, the code will throw a 
% compilation error "! Undefined control sequence" referring to the 
% MyParameters macro. 
%   COMMENTS: 
% Effect first observed in my 'Timelines', a gizmo that that draws 
% charts displaying event lifetimes as horizontal bars and requires 
% left and right edges to be set.
%-----------------------------
%\usepackage[frenchb,greek,russian,ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[greek,russian,ngerman,english]{babel}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\MyParameters{mm}
{   
\tikzmath
    {
    \firstparam=#1;
    \secondparam=#2;        
    }
}   
\NewDocumentCommand\MyDrawing{mm}
    {
    \tikzmath
    {
        \x=\firstparam + #1;
        \y=\secondparam * #2;   
        }
        \draw[red] (\x,\y)--(\x +7,\y+4);
        \draw[blue] (1,5)--(\x,\y);
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\MyParameters{1}{2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\MyDrawing{3}{4}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Might be an idea to quote error as well, not all of us is at our desktops

Comment: Note I retagged to babel as expl3 is not relevant here, you would see the same if you used  `\newcommand` or even `\def`

Comment: @daleif Apologies. I'll pay more attention to that aspect from here on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

babel french makes `;` active for special spacing, you need to turn that off (since it was off at the point you made the definition)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
%-----------------------------
%RN. Sunday 23 August 2015
%   ISSUE:
% Let it be debatable whether my two \NewDocumentCommands are all
% that clever, or even make sense, the fact is they work. If frenchb
% is included as a parameter in babel, the code will throw a 
% compilation error "! Undefined control sequence" referring to the 
% MyParameters macro. 
%   COMMENTS: 
% Effect first observed in my 'Timelines', a gizmo that that draws 
% charts displaying event lifetimes as horizontal bars and requires 
% left and right edges to be set.
%-----------------------------
\usepackage[frenchb,greek,russian,ngerman,english]{babel}
%\usepackage[greek,russian,ngerman,english]{babel}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\MyParameters{mm}
{   
\tikzmath
    {
    \firstparam=#1;
    \secondparam=#2;        
    }
}   
\NewDocumentCommand\MyDrawing{mm}
    {
    \tikzmath
    {
        \x=\firstparam + #1;
        \y=\secondparam * #2;   
        }
        \draw[red] (\x,\y)--(\x +7,\y+4);
        \draw[blue] (1,5)--(\x,\y);
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{;}
\MyParameters{1}{2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\MyDrawing{3}{4}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And back on after the picture.

Comment: @Johannes_B there is only `\end{document}` after the picture:-)

Comment: Sure, i bet there is some text in the original document though. :-p

Comment: @David Carlisle @Johannes_B `\shorthandoff and on` is doing the trick. An undergraduate couldn't guess that in a million years! That's what Tex Exchange is for.

Comment: Naturally, the compiler complains if it sees `\shorthandoff and on` and `frenchb` happens **not** to be loaded into babel. How would I go about making the compilation conditional on the presence/absence of `frenchb`?